# Plotting the outer region contour

Tags: plotting

I have the following code

```
ContourPlot[((11 - j*l)/-j^2)^0.5, {l, 0, 10}, {j, 0, 10}]
```

which generates:

[image]

How can I color the outer region of curves instead of inside?

Something like this:

[image]

Basically I wanted to show the inside of the volume of the following figure with contour (not outside the volume):

[image]

or

[image]

Code:

```
RegionPlot3D[-j^2*y^2 + j*l < 11, {l, 0, 10}, {j, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: A square root of a negative number?

Comment: Your function is imaginary in the white parts. What do you want to plot there? The imaginary part, the argument?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork updated. Thanks

Comment: @halirutan Updated. Thanks

Comment: Change the sign inside the `^0.5` power....Or, for the volume, reverse the inequality.

Answer (score 4):

I know it is very tempting to throw something at Mathematica and enjoy the output. However, if you leave behind all the thinking, you might end up asking questions that really don't make sense.

Your function is real only for the parts that are already plotted. In the white parts, it is complex with only an imaginary part. One possibility is to look at the absolute value of the complex number. Then you get contours on both sides. In the parts that are still white, the function value becomes really large:

```
Show[
 ContourPlot[Abs[((11 - j*l)/-j^2)^0.5], {l, 0, 10}, {j, 0, 10}, 
  Contours -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 3],
 Plot[11/j, {j, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thick, Yellow}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Edit

> Thanks a lot for your comment. I did not release enough details, you are right. I basically wanted to draw the contour of the figure (added to the question) but the inside of the volume not outside. I hope it clears up.

Look, I already explained in detail, why the inside part is plotted and the outside part not. If the inside part is plotted because it is **real** and the outside part not because it is **imaginary**, what can you do to turn this around?

Now you will say, yes, the answer was obvious and bang you get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> `Show[ContourPlot[((11 - j*l)/-j^2)^0.5*(-I), {l, 0, 10}, {j, 0, 10},Contours -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 3],Plot[11/j, {j, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}},PlotStyle -> {Thick, Yellow}]]`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I did not release enough details,  you are right. I basically wanted to draw the contour of the figure (added to the question) but the inside of the volume not outside. I hope it clears up.

Comment: Thanks! How can I obtain the contour that I want then? I am basically trying to show the inside of volume is acceptable area in 2D (for different z values)