# contour of inside of a volume

Tags: plotting

I have the following volume:

```
RegionPlot3D[-j^2*y^2 + j*l < 11, {l, 0, 10}, {j, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

However, I am not able to obtain a 2D graph from it (contour), which shows the region inside the volumes when y is changing (i.e. surface).

[image]

Comment: A similar question was asked https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/162064/plotting-the-outer-region-contour/162066#162066 but it deviated from this question.

Comment: `ContourPlot3D[-j^2*y^2 + j*l == 11, {l, 0, 10}, {j, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 1}]`?